Mac Safari: Disable smooth scrolling in PageDown/PageUp/Spacebar
How do I stop the smooth scrolling animation when I'm paging down and up in Safari using either the PageDown/PageUp keys or the space bar?
I know how to disable smooth scrolling for the arrow keys but that method seems to only change the one-line scrolling animation, not the whole-page scrolling.
I'm on Sequoia 15.1.1 with a MBP builtin keyboard. I know I've done this before but I can't find anything now.

I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/466039/disabling-smooth-scrolling-in-os-x-lion-when-using-page-up-down – defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false – this applies to all apps, not just Safari
